# Boolean algebra simplification proof without truth table

Tags: boolean-algebra

How to prove that $A\bar B+(\bar A + B)C=A\bar B+C$?

I don't even know how to start. The distribution law doesn't help. All other laws are not applicable.

Similarly, how to prove that
$AD+B\bar D+C\bar D+A\bar C+\bar A\bar D=A+\bar D$?

Comment: Distribution helps together with $D+\overline{D}C=D+C$. Can you show what you have done?

Comment: @zkutch, I don't know how to start.

Comment: $A\bar B+(\bar A + B)C = A\bar B+\overline{A\bar B}C$

Comment: @zkutch, got it! What about the second?

Comment: the second one does not look right, $B$ should be on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easies way is to compare the truth tables.

\begin{align} 
A\bar B+(\bar A + B)C&=A\bar B+C
\tag{1}\label{1}
\\
AD+B\bar D+C\bar D+A\bar C+\bar A\bar D
&=A+\bar D
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

Things can also be simplified by checking
if eqns hold for both values of one variable.

For example, let's check \eqref{1} for $C=0$

\begin{align} 
A\bar B+(\bar A + B)0&=A\bar B+0
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
A\bar B&=A\bar B
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}

and $C=1$ separately:

\begin{align} 
A\bar B+(\bar A + B)1&=A\bar B+1
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
A\bar B+(\bar A + B)(A+\bar A)&=1
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
A\bar B+A\bar A + AB+\bar A\bar A+\bar AB&=1
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
A\bar B+0 + AB+\bar A+\bar AB&=1
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
A\bar B+0 + AB+\bar A+\bar AB&=1
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
A(\bar B+B)+\bar A(1+B)&=1
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
A+\bar A&=1
\tag{11}\label{11}
.
\end{align}

Similarly, for \eqref{2}, check $A=0$

\begin{align} 
0D+B\bar D+C\bar D+0\bar C+1\bar D
&=0+\bar D
\tag{12}\label{12}
,\\
B\bar D+(C+1)\bar D
&=\bar D
\tag{13}\label{13}
,\\
B\bar D+\bar D
&=\bar D
\tag{14}\label{14}
,\\
(B+1)\bar D
&=\bar D
\tag{15}\label{15}
,
\end{align}

and $A=1$:

\begin{align} 
1D+B\bar D+C\bar D+1\bar C+0\bar D
&=1+\bar D
\tag{16}\label{16}
,\\
D+B\bar D+C\bar D+\bar C
&=1
\tag{17}\label{17}
,\\
D+B\bar D+C\bar D+\bar C(D+\bar D)
&=1
\tag{18}\label{18}
,\\
D+B\bar D+C\bar D+\bar CD+\bar C\bar D
&=1
\tag{19}\label{19}
,\\
(1+\bar C)D+(B+C+\bar C)\bar D
&=1
\tag{20}\label{20}
,\\
D+\bar D
&=1
\tag{21}\label{21}
.
\end{align}

Comment: It is sure a good way, but algebraic manipulations might be more elegant in this case.